# What does "that in "that goes by" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Schindler's List (1993)*, Oskar confronts Goeth, who is killing his factory workers:

> Oskar: I go to work the other day. Nobody's there. Nobody tells me
> about this.  I have to find out. I have to go in. Everybody's gone.
>
> Goeth: They're not gone. They're here.
>
> Oskar: They're mine! Every day **that goes by**, I'm losing money. Every
> worker that is shot costs me money. I have to find somebody else. I
> have to train them.

What does "that in "that goes by" refer to?

Comment: It doesn't refer to anything. It's a subordinator introducing the relative clause "that goes by". It functions as a marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding *that goes by* to the name of a time period (day, hour, month...) just emphasises the idea of the passage of time. It just means *every day which passes.*

Answer (score 0):

the idiom is: time goes by

days, weeks, hours, minutes, and other time periods can be said to "go by", which means: pass

Here, **that goes by** refers to **every day**.

Every day that goes by = Every day that passes or every passing day.

Two famous titles using this idea are:

- A British Comedy series called: As Time Goes By
- A jazz song that was in Casablanca and a huge hit.

Enjoy!

[As Time Goes By](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d22CiKMPpaY)